# Ошибка 404 Spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

Дело в том, что spring не видит jsp. В чем может быть проблема ?

```
@Controller
 public class UsersController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/users",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getUsers(){
    return new ModelAndView("users","command",new Users());
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/add",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addUsers(@ModelAttribute("users") Users users){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("main");
    modelAndView.addObject("users", users);

    return modelAndView;
}

}
```

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="th" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Main</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

<spring:form action="/users" method="get" modelAttribute="users">
<input type="text" value="${users.name}"/>
<input type="password" value="${users.password}"/>
</spring:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Настройки:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.spring.santaasus")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setSuffix("/resources/");
        resolver.setPrefix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

`.jsp` файл находится в `resources`.

[image]

```
public class Applicationinit implements WebApplicationInitializer{
private static final String DISPATCHER = "dispatcher";


public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(WebConfig.class);
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER,new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
    servlet.addMapping("/");
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

   }
}



@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.spring.santaasus")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("resources/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
  }
}
```

Comment: А как у вас объявлен ViewResolver? И какая структура проекта, в смысле где находятся JSP.

Comment: добавил в описание

Comment: Имена папок одинаковые,я поторопился.Не думаю, что из-за расположения файла main.jsp могут быть проблемы.Даже если создать WEB-INF и закинуть туда jsp файл, ничего не изменится.

Comment: Вы spring-boot используете?

Comment: Нет,использую: spring data jpa,web mvc

Comment: А где тогда у вас web.xml и servlet-dispatcher.xml? У вас похоже вообще не веб-апп, а нечто непонятное.

Comment: Вместо xml использовал JavaConfig.

Comment: Смотрите мой ответ, этот вариант у меня работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас перепутаны местами `prefix` и `suffix`, т.е. должно быть:

```
resolver.setPrefix("/resources/"); // то что перед именем вью
resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");        // то что после имени вью
```

Так же папочка `resources` должна находиться в `webapp`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Исправил. HTTP Status 404 - /resources/main.jsp

Comment: @santaasuss а папочка resources где у вас находиться? относительно WEB-INF

Comment: Прикрепил изображение